# What is the difference between MIME, Internet media type and HTTP?

Tags: http, mime-types, content-type

From what I have read, MIME is [something that is used for encoding e-mails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME).

Then there's this thing called [Internet media types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).
We have Internet media types like `text/plain`, `application/json`, `image/png` etc.

Then we have HTTP protocol with its `Content-Type` headers, examples of valid headers include:

`Content-Type: text/plain`
`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`
`Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=blah` ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages))

So is string such as "`text/plain; charset=utf-8`" an expression bound to HTTP protocol, MIME standard or a completely valid Internet media type?

What exactly are the relations between each of these protocols?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Internet Media Type" is the correct term for "MIME type".

"Content-Type" is the name of the HTTP (and mail) header field that carries the media type in the field value.

Comment: What about the `; charset=...` suffix: is this part of Internet Media Type, or rather MIME/HTTP? If so, what about `; boundary=...` suffix?

Comment: Parameters can be considered as part of the type.

Comment: Currently, Wikipedia say "XML documents must be served with an XML Internet media type (often confused with MIME type) such as...", but I there isn't a citation.